# In jquery how can I call function when someone hasn't typed in 1 second?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a `<div>` that has a list of items being `load()`ed into it containing a keyword typed in a text input triggered by `keyup()`. When I also run a jquery plugin that highlights that keyword in the respective search items on keyup() it slows the page WAY down and can even crash my browser.

So I'm wondering if there is a way that I can only trigger this highlighting function after a person hasn't typed any characters in a second or two and THEN trigger the highlighter. Or is there maybe some way I can keep it at the end of the queue so that it always triggers last?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `setTimeout` to delay the call to highlight, and `clearTimeout` if a new keystroke is received before that one second has passed:

```
var timeout;

$('#my-input').keyup(function() {

    // clear previous timeout if there was one
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);

    // set new one
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {

        // make your highlight call here

    }, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep a global timeout variable like `var myTimeout = null;`. Inside your keyup() handler, you can start a `myTimeout = window.setTimeout(highlight, 1500);` and cancel the (previous) timeout if it is still running. Inside the highlight function you reset myTimeout to null again.

Something in the lines of

```
var myTimeout = null;

$('#whatever').keyup(function() {
   if(myTimeout) clearTimeout(myTimeout);
   ....
   myTimeout = window.setTimeout(highlight, 1500);
});

function highlight() {
   myTimeout = null;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout` to set the function to run after 2s and user `clearTimeout` to cancel this before the 2s are finished:

```
var timeoutId;

$("input").keyup(function(){

    if(timeoutId){
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }

    timeoutId = setTimeout(intervalFunc, 2000); 
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tdbsY/